# How to enable cpuset on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, server, cpu, process, resource-limiting

I have set up CPU sets with `cset` in Ubuntu 12.04, but they are not respected. Processes just use all the CPU they can, no matter what set they are assigned to.

It seems that `cpuset` is not enabled. How can I enable `cpuset`?

Comment: 'm... see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/182434

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to using other utility `cpulimit`?

1) Install cpulimit by issuing `sudo apt-get install cpulimit`

2) Limit the process in question like this (say we want to restrict java to use not more than 30 % of CPU)

```
cpulimit -e java -l 30
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with `nice` and `renice` command in the terminal.

for example: `sudo renice -n -15 -u username`

The options are:

-n=priority from -20 to 20 (where -20 is highest)

-p=process id (found in task manager)

-u=all events user started

Or do you mean something else?

Comment: The original question was how to enable cpuset. Does nice/renice help with enabling cpuset, or does it achieve cpuset functionality, and if so, how? From the current answer, it's not clear what the commands do.

Comment: nice / renice don't limit cpu-usage, they just alter the cpu-priority (niceness) of the process(es). cpuset is quit another fish.